# Assigned register collision when inline assembly compiled with clang

Tags: clang, inline-assembly, compiler-bug

Consider the following sample program (targeting Linux/x86-64):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  unsigned arg1 = strtoul(argv[1], NULL, 0);
  unsigned arg2 = strtoul(argv[2], NULL, 0);
  asm(
    "mov %[arg1], %%ecx\n\t"
    "add %[arg2], %[arg1]\n\t"
    "add %[arg2], %%ecx\n\t"
    "xchg %%ecx, %[arg2]"
    : [arg1] "+&abdSD" (arg1), [arg2] "+&abdSD" (arg2)
    :
    : "cc", "ecx");
  printf("%u %u\n", arg1, arg2);
}
```

(`xchg` is used just for easy grepping of compiled instructions in listing.)

With GCC, it works as expected - different registers are assigned to arg1 and arg2, for example:

```
    11bf:       e8 cc fe ff ff          callq  1090 <strtoul@plt>
    11c4:       89 da                   mov    %ebx,%edx
    11c6:       89 d1                   mov    %edx,%ecx
    11c8:       01 c2                   add    %eax,%edx
    11ca:       01 c1                   add    %eax,%ecx
    11cc:       91                      xchg   %eax,%ecx
```

(so, arg1 in edx, arg2 in eax)

But, compiling with Clang (confirmed on 6.0 and 10.0) results in assigning the same register for arg1 and arg2:

```
  401174:       e8 d7 fe ff ff          callq  401050 <strtoul@plt>
  401179:       44 89 f0                mov    %r14d,%eax ; <--
  40117c:       89 c1                   mov    %eax,%ecx
  40117e:       01 c0                   add    %eax,%eax ; <-- so, arg1 and arg2 both in eax
  401180:       01 c1                   add    %eax,%ecx
  401182:       91                      xchg   %eax,%ecx
```

The issue remains with multiple variations as e.g.: `+` instead of `+&` in constraint strings; numeric forms like `%0` to address operands; replacing `xchg` with another rare instruction; and so on.

I have been expecting, from the basic principles, that compilerʼs logic to assign output locations will always assign different locations to different output operands, whatever constraints are defined for them; and the same works among the input operands set. (Modifiers like '+', '&' add more rules to placement logic but canʼt erode the main principles.)

Is there a some trivial aspect Iʼve overlooked?

UPD: [reported](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=48862) to LLVM.

Comment: Looks like clang is getting it wrong to me.  Is there some reason you feel the need to enumerate registers instead of just using `"+r"`?  That appears to work correctly.

Comment: Just to add: Clang allows it if you specify `"+a"` for both arg1 and arg2, which is clearly impossible in this case.  gcc rejects this as "impossible constraints."

Comment: @DavidWohlferd With "+r" it can (even with GCC) assign `*cx` so it will collide with explicit usage of `ecx` in the example. X86 has lots of instructions with fixed registers, and it looks weird to declare such a register fake input/output just to exclude it from assignment. I guess this is fixed by declaring clobbering of `ecx`, but with Clang behavior Iʼm unsure in such guarantee.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd Well, this issue with "+a" looks like suggesting a bug...

Comment: Either you are assigning a value to ecx in the constraints (which should prevent it from being used in other terms with `r`) or you are overwriting it inside the asm and need to clobber it (which should also prevent it from being used with other terms).  Clang seems to get it right with `r`.  It's just a problem if you enumerate registers, where it apparently assumes the explicit list overrides the other checks (and yeah, that seems wrong).

Comment: Looks lke a good MCVE, go ahead and report on https://bugs.llvm.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=new-bugs

Comment: You seem to claim `"+r" can pick ECX despite an `"ecx"` or `"rcx"` clobber with GCC and clang.  That would be a separate bug that you should also report.  Or if you didn't use an `"ecx"` clobber, then your inline asm was buggy.  Your inline asm template must not modify registers that aren't outputs or clobbers.

Comment: @PeterCordes No, with explicit ecx clobber I haven't found its assignment. But seeing this I'd suspect that some more complex cases e.g. "rm" for two parameters could fall into a similar result.

Comment: I re-read your earlier comment.  It seems you just wished that `"+r"` would avoid ECX because it's sometimes needed as a fixed register for some instructions (like variable-count `shl`).  By that logic, it should avoid every single register except maybe EBP - they all have some implicit uses.  Much more sane to simply require you to ask for a value already in ECX, or declare a clobber on ECX, or any other register, if that's what your specific asm template needs, instead of trying to make it sometimes safe to leave out some registers when you describe your code to the compiler.

Comment: But that's separate from the actual buggy behaviour you're seeing.  Your LLVM bug report is valid, that's a real bug.  2 separate outputs need to be in different registers even if they're also inputs that are known to have the same input value.  GCC and LLVM don't try to parse the asm template string, just blindly fill in `%stuff`, so it's not going to depend on which instructions.  A template like `"nop # arg1 = %0 , arg2 = %1"` and looking at the compiler's `-S` asm output would be sufficient.  (And less cluttered than disassembly).

Comment: @PeterCordes I hadn't asked it to exclude ecx automatically from assignment. Maybe my formulation wasn't clear but the gist was to exclude clashes with explicit lists like "abdSD" from the very beginning. Thanks for the PR approval.

Comment: @Netch: I was talking about [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65644864/assigned-register-collision-when-inline-assembly-compiled-with-clang?noredirect=1#comment116069251_65644864) - *it can (even with GCC) assign `*cx` so it will collide with explicit usage of ecx in the example. X86 has lots of instructions with fixed registers, and it looks weird to declare such a register fake input/output just to exclude it from assignment.*  Anyway, let's just forget about that comment if you're not still thinking anything like that.  `"+r"` and an `"ecx"` clobber sounds totally normal.